# Function depending on a cell word

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to copy the .setValue if a word ("Refresh") appears (from a dropdown) in a cell.

The copy part works perfectly but the first part does not.

```
function myRecalculate(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("------");
var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("News_raw");
var cell1 = sheet1.getRange('D3');
var values = cell1.getValues();

for(var i in values){

  if(values[i][0].match("Refresh")!=null){
     //cell contains "Refresh". Do something 
 
 
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("News_raw"); 
  var cell2 = sheet2.getRange('C1');

  cell2.setValue('https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=');

   }

  }

}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add all the relevant details into the question.

Comment: Hi there @AntorCha! I don't understand why this answer isn't valid for you. Could you please clarify why in order to help you better?